# Example of a Banach lattice satisfying some conditions

Tags: banach-spaces

Let a Banach lattice $E$ satisfying in the following conditions:

- The lattice operations of the dual $E'$ are weak* sequentially continuous.
- $E$ is not $σ$-Dedekind complete.

Is there such  Banach lattice?

Comment: You should define Dedekind $\sigma$ complete.

Comment: E is σ-Dedekind complete if every nonempty countable subset A⊂E wich has an upper bound ( i.e there is some a∈E such that for each x∈A x≤a ) admets a supremum, i.e the least upper bound.